# How can I make crontab work with curl and ampersands in URLs?

Tags: curl, cron

I have to send a GET request to the URL

```
http://localhost:8082/email-bulk?customer=Martin+Thoma&handler_pid=foo+f0a474c5-3cb1-4872-8689-c65cedb15bff&format_string=%7Breceived%3A%25y%25m%25d%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D%7Bfile_extension%7D&minutes_email=2
```

every minute. So I set the crontab entry to

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent "http://localhost:8082/email-bulk?customer=Martin+Thoma&handler_pid=foo+f0a474c5-3cb1-4872-8689-c65cedb15bff&format_string=%7Breceived%3A%25y%25m%25d%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D%7Bfile_extension%7D&minutes_email=2"
```

But the server does not receive any request.

With

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent http://localhost:8082/email-bulk?customer=Martin+Thoma&handler_pid=foo+f0a474c5-3cb1-4872-8689-c65cedb15bff&format_string=%7Breceived%3A%25y%25m%25d%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D+%7Bfoo%7D%7Bfile_extension%7D&minutes_email=2
```

it receives a request to

```
http://localhost:8082/email-bulk?customer=Martin+Thoma
```

How can I make this work without using an external script?

Answer (score 1):

Not using quotes and escaping `&` and `%` with `\` seems to work. But I still would like to know why using quotes doesn't work / which characters need to be escaped and why.

(So I will not accept this answer)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your double quotes with single quotes, and the shell will not attempt to parse the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use quotes, your shell will interpret your string like a set of commands split by the `&` and executed everything before the `&` in the background. (unless you escape the character `\&`)

To test this try this in your terminal

```
$ echo 1 & echo 2
```

The output will be something like:

```
$ echo 1 & echo 2
[1] 2188
2
1
[1]  + done       echo 1
```

In your example the part of the command that will be executed in the background will be:

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent http://localhost:8082/email-bulk?customer=Martin+Thoma &
```

But the rest of the string since is not a valid command you will get error, for example:

```
$ echo 1 & foo   
[1] 2244
1
[1]  + done       echo 1
zsh: command not found: foo
```

From the man [bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell.

Therefore by using quotes, your shell doesn't parse the string, example:

```
$ echo "1 & foo"
1 & foo
```

Depends on your shell what to escape and what not, check this answer for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296147/53084